# Handles not importing plot to GUI - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, plot

I have a .fig file with its own GUI controlling .m script. And I have a user-defined script for calculations. There's a plot in my user-defined script which I want in my G.U.I. The .fig file consists of a set of 5 axes plots like this:

[image]

my user-defined script with the function for plotting is like this:

```
function MyScript = MyFile(handles)
```

Ignoring the data used to obtain the plot itself, my plotting function is written in the same user-defined function as

```
plot(handles.x,y)
```

In the GUI script I call MyScript:

```
% --- Executes just before SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI is made visible.
function SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for SoftwareMonitoringToolGUI
handles.output = hObject;

MyScript(handles);
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

NOTE: I am just trying to get 1 of the plots working at the moment (in this query). I COULD use subplot but I want to visually display all 5 plots at once and eventually add more options like sliders etc.

Comment: How do you target a specific axis? The plot command might need the axes handle input if you don't make each axes current before each plot. (It's better to specify the handle to `plot`.)

Comment: It's not just plots I am having this problem with. It's also figures. I have a different thread which I think demonstrates the point more clearly. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640955/import-figures-to-matlab-gui-using-handles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the rigth tag names of the axes (the tag names can be changed in teh in Inspector >> tag". Currently your axes names are "axis1, axis2, ...". Change your code to:

```
plot(handles.axis1,x,y)
```

Now, this code should plot the data in y against the data in x and show it in axis1.

Comment: Thanks, this partly worked but I can't get it to work with my other figures. I've left an example in this thread if you have any time to view it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640955/import-figures-to-matlab-gui-using-handles