# Import figures to MATLAB GUI using handles?

Tags: matlab, loops, user-interface, plot, handles

How can I literally take these figures and place them in the axes windows of my GUI?

I am not sure where to place handles in my user-defined code in the example below. I have 4 figures in total which look similar to this example. I want the 4 figures to be displayed in my GUI window and not in separate windows, so i've created 4 axes windows in the .fig file.

The code for this particular figure draws a grid of 66 black and white rectangles based on whether or not a value in `MyVariable` is a 1 or a 0. Black if `MyVariable` is a 1, White if `MyVariable` is 0. I have a file for my .fig GUI, one file to control the GUI and one with user-defined code that links to the GUI.

```
function test = MyScript(handles)
```

*lots of code in between*

```
% Initialize and clear plot window 
figure(2); clf;

% Plot the west wall array panels depending on whether or not they are
% shaded or unshaded
for x = 1:11
     for y = 1:6
  if (MyVariable(x,y) == 1)
  rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1] ,'EdgeColor', 'w', 'facecolor', 'k')
  else if(MyVariable(x,y) == 0)
  rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1], 'facecolor', 'w')
end
end
end
end

title('West Wall Array',... 
  'FontWeight','bold')

axis off
```

The figure for the above code looks like this:
[image]

The function definition contains all of my script code for all 4 plots because I didn't partition my script into individual functions earlier on.

My GUI script code contains:

```
   MyScript(handles);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DMR sais, it's necesary to set the 'CurrentAxes'. For example, if you want to plot into the axis with the tag name 'axis1' you should simply add:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
```

to your code. Below is a very simple example for a figure containing a 'axis1' and 'axis2' using your code (corrected) code from above. Im not really shure wether you want to plot on an axis on your gui itself or a separate figure. I hope I covered both cases.

```
function varargout = Test(varargin)

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Test_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Test_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

% --- Executes just before Test is made visible.
function Test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)


% Choose default command line output for Test
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

plot(handles.axes2,-2*pi:0.1:2*pi,sin(-2*pi:0.1:2*pi));

% Initialize and clear plot window 


MyVariable = ones(11,6);
MyVariable(1:5,1) = 0;

axes(handles.axes1);

for x = 1:11
    for y = 1:6
        if (MyVariable(x,y) == 1)
            rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1] ,'EdgeColor', 'w', 'facecolor', 'k');
        elseif(MyVariable(x,y) == 0)
            rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1], 'facecolor', 'w');
        end
    end
end

title('West Wall Array',... 
  'FontWeight','bold')

figure(2); clf;

for x = 1:11
    for y = 1:6
        if (MyVariable(x,y) == 1)
            rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1] ,'EdgeColor', 'w', 'facecolor', 'k');
        elseif(MyVariable(x,y) == 0)
            rectangle('position', [x-1, y-1, 1, 1], 'facecolor', 'w');
        end
    end
end

title('West Wall Array',... 
  'FontWeight','bold')

function varargout = Test_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;
```

Your guide GUI should look like this:
[image]

And your result like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This has fixed my problem although axis values still appear on 3 of my plots and this is unwanted. 

This is an image of what I have: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104069213/GUI%20example%201.png Figure 'West Wall Array' is exactly the format I want. The other images titled 'Array' have values on the images and the images are skewed. They didn't look like this prior to putting them in the GUI. This is what they looked like as separate figures, the same as 'West Wall Array': 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104069213/GUI%20example%202.png

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the axis to plot into prior each plot command by setting the 'CurrentAxes' property of the figure.

Within GUIDE, you can tag a given axis, for example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-with-multiple-axes-guide.html . Then within your drawing code, indicate which axis should be plotted into via the 'set' function and 'CurrentAxes' property.

A simple example is below, though it doesn't use GUIDE, only basic subplot axis handles:

```
% plots in most recent axis by default (ax2)
fig = figure;
ax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
plot(rand(1,10));

% indicate that you want to plot in ax1 instead
fig = figure;
ax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
set(gcf, 'CurrentAxes', ax1);
plot(rand(1,10));
```

Comment: I need to use GUIDE because I will be adding a drop down menu etc later for other features. My figures, as indicated above, don't use the plot function though. I'm using the rectangle function to generate the full plot so how can I do it using that function? Also, since this example doesn't use GUIDE i'm unsure how i'd split the code between the user-defined file and link it to the GUI file so I can use it with handles.

Comment: You can add dropdown menus, push buttons, checkboxes, etc. using the [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) command.